# code won't run after run task ---------- error: invalid value 'c++23' in '-std=c++23'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Im using vsc and none of my programs will run using the "run code" button in the top right corner. I can run the code using ./ in the terminal.

Here is what is outputted when I run build:

Executing task: C/C++: clang++ build active file

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/tst.cpp -o /Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/tst

When I use the "run code" button I get the following error:

error: invalid value 'c++23' in '-std=c++23'

Here is what is run in the terminal after clicking "run code"

cd "/Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/" && ***g++*** tst.cpp -o tst && "/Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/"tst

So the issue is that g++ is used instead of clang++. When I change g++ to clang++ like:

cd "/Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/" && ***clang++*** tst.cpp -o tst && "/Users/ben/CS2/meal_plan/test/"tst

It runs.

So it seems like the wrong compiler is used when clicking "run code." Correct? How do I change that? I changed g++ to clang++ in my json file and it still doesnt, work I added the updated json file below.

warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension

so I was messing around with the default Cpp standard and set it to c++23 and now I'm not sure what is happening.

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++23"
    },
    {
        "name": "mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [

    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    }
]
```

}

New tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [


    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-std=c++17",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Apparently your compiler doesn't support C++23. (And your programs do *not* compile)

Comment: "They all compile" -- I doubt that, because you cite a compiler error. Can you compile a program from the commandline? What is the exact call used to compile? BTW: Compiler version matter, they're missing from your question. Please, as a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Did you try setting just c++17 or 20 (or just C++11 for that matter!)?

Comment: Have compilers already activated that as a valid standard version, or is it sill `c++2b`?

Comment: The instructions for macOS are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) I would try the c++17 like the documentation tells you first and get that working.

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt I updated my post with the commandline arguments. It seems that g++ is used instead of clang++ and I'm not sure how to change that so when I click "run code" it uses the correct compiler.

Comment: @sweenish as far as I can tell, it's still `--std=c++2b`, and C++23 has [_experimental_](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) support. There are many language features that are not functional yet. @OP, stick to C++20 or earlier.

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct.  So why don't you put the path to the compiler you want into `tasks.json` ?

Comment: @ Ben Voigt What part of the tasks.json should I change? I changed the command label (I added my new json file in my post) and it still won't work.